# On coalescence and the usage thereof

Tags: word-usage

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coalescence defines "coalescence" as:

Noun (countable and uncountable, plural coalescences)

> The act of coalescing.
> (phonology) The merging of two segments into one.

I'm wondering if it would be appropriate to say something like "this coalescence" in reference to a single aggregation of many things together. Can I say that a cloud is a coalescence of other smaller clouds?

Wiktionary referring to it as "the act of coalescing" or the "merging" of segments makes me think like it's an intangible thing like a verb inflected as a noun, sort of like run/running (I can say "I had a good run" as a noun but it would be inappropriate to think of it as an actual thing)

Comment: It's just the action, not the things that coalesce. The things would be a collection.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore, yeah, that's what I'm trying to verbalize here. The whole is different than simply the sum of the parts. For example, you wouldn't call a nebula 'a collection of cosmic gases and dust', regardless of size. A nebula is a thing unto itself. Granted nebula has a very nice name for its particular manifestation. Is a drop of rain a collection of suspended water vapor? I mean, maybe, but that's an awkward way to describe it, you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This interesting question reveals gaps in the dictionary world. To take just two examples:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coalescence)
> *coalescence*
> the process of coming or growing together to form one thing or system

> [Oxford Learners Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/coalescence)
> *coalescence*
> noun
> ​the act or process of coming together to form one larger group, substance, etc.

Cambridge and Oxford both focus on the *process* of coming together rather than on the object that is created by the coming together.

Collins and Merriam Webster make no attempt to define the word.

Your quote from Wikipedia is too restrictive. It refers to "two" segments, whereas the general definitions above and elsewhere apply to any number above one.

Now to the question of whether you may use the word to apply to the object formed by the process. I have found no dictionary definition that justifies this, although it seems a reasonable and useful thing to do.

However, it is useful and suggestive to look at synonyms of *coalescence*:

> [Thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/coalescence)
> offers:
> clotting, clump, lump, array, batch, battery, body, bunch, bundle, cluster and others

Similarly,

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/coalescence)
> offers:
> agglomeration, amalgamation, blend, commingling, compounding, fusion, intermingling, intermixture, mingling, mix, mixture, synthesis,
> combination, combining, connecting, connection, consolidation, coupling, junction, linking, merger, merging, unification, union and others

Some of these synonyms relate to the process, some to the created objects, some to both, justifying the use of the word as an object as well as a process.

Hence a large cloud is a coalescence of smaller clouds. A coalescence of opinion is a unified body of opinion formed by the reconciliation of several opinions.

And to finish, here is an example from contemporary game playing:

> [Polygon Gaming](https://www.polygon.com/genshin-impact-guides/23271488/starlight-coalescence-locations-minacious-isle-puzzle)
> *... Our Starlight Coalescence guide will list all the Starlight Coalescence locations and provide guidance through any of the related puzzles on Minacious Isle. ...*

Comment: Your "opinion" example suggests that there are context-specific words, e.g. "concensus" might be right there.

Comment: @Barmar A good point. Such shifts seem to happen easily when chasing a sequence of synonyms. I actually wonder if there is such a thing as an "exact" synonym. It might make a good question one day.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can say that, "a cloud is a **coalescence** of other smaller clouds". People however are likely to use other words equivalent to "coalescence" for ease of use. Also when you are using the comparative "smaller" for one thing, you ought to use a different word signifying extent or magnitude for the other thing. These are the sentences you are more likely to hear.

> "An average"/"A big" cloud is a **fusion** of other smaller clouds.
>
> "An average"/"A big" cloud is a **mass** of other smaller clouds.

[Coalescence usage example](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/coalescence)(The Britannica Dictionary)

```
 A glacier formed by coalescence of ice masses
 A coalescence of forces
```

[Fusion](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/fusion)(The Britannica Dictionary)  a combination or mixture of things

```
A fusion of different methods
A fusion of musical styles
The show is a fusion of news and entertainment.
```

Comment: You don't seem to appreciate Barmar's comment above, that there's a difference between the action of coming together, which *coalescence* refers to, and the object that results, which the OP is asking about.

Comment: I agree I approached the question in a mechanical way. A better answer has since been provided by Anton. This answer also incidentally illuminated the often overlooked real phenomenon of gaps in the dictionary world.